# Replace all values in a column with math from that variable

Tags: python, pandas

How do I replace the value for price (stored in the number variable) with the updateNum Variable.

```py
for index, row in maindf.iterrows():
    number = row["price"]
    updateNum = number / 10 ** 2
```

If I print the dataframe after the code below the price values aren't updated but If I print the updateNum variable it displays the correctly updated variable.

```py
    df.replace(to_replace=number, value=updateNum, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply redefine the column with the desired formula:

```
df['price'] = df['price'] / 10 ** 2
```

This will overwrite the column price with the desired calculation.

Comment: This just sets all the price values to 0, which I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: Nevermind this has fixed the issue, thanks! Not sure why the values displayed as 0.